# Hadoop Performance When retrieving Data Only

Tags: hadoop

We know that performance of Hadoop may be increased by adding more data nodes. My question is: if we want to retrieve the data only without the need to process it or analyze it, is adding more data nodes will be useful? or it won't increase performance at all because we have retrieve operations only without any computations or map reduce jobs?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer in parts:

1. If you only retrieve information from a hadoop cluster or HDFS then
   it is similar to `Cat` command in linux, meaning only reading data
   not processing.
2. If you want some calculations like SUM, AVG or any other aggregate
   functions on top of your data then comes the concept of REDUCE ,
   hence Map reduce comes into picture.
3. So hadoop is useful or worthy when your data is Huge and you do
   calculations also. I think their is no performance benefits while
   reading a small amount of data in HDFS than reading a Large amount
   of data in HDFS (just think like you are storing your data in RDBMS
   regularly and you only query select * statements on daily basis),
   but when your data grows exponentially and you want to do
   calculations your RDBMS query would take time to execute.
4. For Map reduce to work efficiently on huge data sets , you need to
       have good amount of nodes and computing power, depending upon your
       use case.